# Реализация функции работы с файлами с/с++

Tags: c++

В данной функции есть два буфера: *bufin* и *bufout*. в буфер *bufin* считывается информация из файла размером 8 мегабайт, затем данная информация разбивается на блоки размером 160000, после этого каждый шифруется и записывается в буфер *bufout*, но поскольку размер последнего блока меньше 160000 то из-за этого во время выполнения программы выскакивает ошибка.

Как дополнить последний блок нулями, чтобы его размер был равен 160000?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "rijndael.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
#define KEYBITS 256
#define bufsize 160000

unsigned char bufin[bufsize],bufout[bufsize];

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
unsigned long rk[RKLENGTH(KEYBITS)];
unsigned char key[KEYLENGTH(KEYBITS)];
int i;
int nrounds,realreads;
char password[80], sfname[80],dfname[80];
FILE *input,*output;

unsigned char plaintext[16];
unsigned char ciphertext[16];
clock_t t1,t2;
float tm;

/*
if (argc < 3)
{
fputs("Missing argument\n", stderr);
return 1;
}*/

printf("Enter key: ");
gets(password);
printf("Enter source file name: ");
gets(sfname);
printf("Enter destination file name: ");
gets(dfname);
t1=clock();
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(key); i++)
key[i] = *password != 0 ? (*password)++ : 0;

input=fopen(sfname,"rb");
output = fopen(dfname, "wb");
if (output == NULL)
{
fputs("File write error", stderr);
return 1;
}

nrounds = rijndaelSetupEncrypt(rk, key, 256);
//do
{
realreads=fread(bufin,1,bufsize,input);
int j=0;
while(j<=realreads){
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
plaintext[i] = bufin[i+j];
}
rijndaelEncrypt(rk, nrounds, plaintext, ciphertext);
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
bufout[i+j]=ciphertext[i];
}
j+=16;
}
fwrite(bufout,1,realreads,output);
}//while(realreads==bufsize);
t2=clock();
tm=(float)(t2-t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("t=%f\n",tm);
fclose(output);
}
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть как то отформатировали и код и текст, читать ведь не возможно.

Comment: @sergey88, про fopen(), fread() и fwrite() прочитали?

Comment: @sergey88, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: я пытался сделать это, но у меня ничего не вышло

Comment: @sergey88, 

    но у меня ничего не вышло

прочесть про 3 функции не удалось?

Или что-то конкретное не понятно,

 или программа компилируется с ошибками (какими?),

 или не выдает желаемый результат? Если последнее, то что проиходит (что Вы видите на экране)?

Comment: не понимаю как разбить информацию в буфере 1 на блоки по 16 и затем передать ее в буфер2

Comment: @sergey88, так Вы про fread прочитали?

    unsigned char ciphertext[16];
    ....
    if (fread(ciphertext, sizeof(ciphertext), 1, input) != 1)

вот тут в ciphertext будут Ваши 16 байт.

Я не знаю точно, что делает Ваша функция 

    rijndaelDecrypt(rk, nrounds, ciphertext, plaintext);

но подозреваю, что расшифровывает 16 байт в буфере ciphertext и размещает расшифрованные 16 байт в plaintext. 

Видимо это и есть ожидаемая Вами *передача в буфер2*.

--

Откровенно говоря, я бы читал так 

    int l = fread(ciphertext, 1, 16, input);

а потом проверял `l`. Если не EOF и не 16, то ругался бы.

Comment: @sergey88, IMHO "добивать нулями" надо не до 16000, а до ближайшего числа, большего realreads **и кратного 16**. Т.е. прочли, например 30 байт, надо добавит 2 нуля, получив 32 байта, обработать эти данные и завершиться.

Получится что-то вроде

    if (!(realreads = fread(bufin,1,bufsize,input))
        break; // конец данных
    int j, block_length = (realreads+15) & ~0xf; // cбросим 4 младшие бита, получим число, кратное 16
    for (j = realreads; j < block_length; j++)
       bufin[j] = 0;
    realreads = block_length;
    j = 0;
    .... // Ваша обработка блока данных

Answer (score 1):

вынесено из комментария.

---

"дополнять нулями" надо не до 16000, а до ближайшего числа, большего *realreads* и кратного 16.

Т.е. прочли, например 30 байт, надо добавить 2 нуля, получив 32 байта, обработать эти данные и завершиться. Получится что-то вроде:

```
if (!(realreads = fread(bufin,1,bufsize,input)) break;
// конец данных
int j, block_length = (realreads+15) & ~0xf;
// cбросим 4 младшие бита, получим число, кратное 16
for (j = realreads; j < block_length; j++) bufin[j] = 0;
realreads = block_length;
j = 0;
...
// Ваша обработка блока данных
```